# How to calculate the probability that among 5 at least 2 (or more) users would participate

Tags: probability

I have 100 users, and built from these users, there are 20 groups (i.e., each has 5 users). I have the individual probability scores per user regarding their participation in a their group space.

I just want to calculate the probability in each group that at least 2 (or more) users would participate in the group space. However, I am not clear how to achieve this task, as I want to calculate the probability score based on the "at least" participation. I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the parameters of participation are, but in general, these problems are often more easily approached by considering the probability that either none or one of the users participate.  The desired probability is then one minus that.

Comment: How close do you want to be? While it is not exact, it is a decent approximation to use the average probability per person. Again, this will not give you the exact results, but depending on the spread of the data, you may have an easier time just using the average and pretending that everyone has that average probability. Then it is fairly easy to calculate the probability that at least two people in each group uses the group space.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe that is not a very good approximation, suppose two dudes go with probability $1$ and the rest with probability $0$ for example.

Comment: @Jorge Fernandez Yes, let's consider that. Then there is a 0% chance that at least two users in every group would participate in group space (you need a minimum of 40 users to participate in group space). If we use averages, the average that a single user will participate is 2%. In a single group, the probability that at least two people in the group will participate is $1-.98^5-5\cdot .98^4\cdot .02 \approx 0.003842$. Now, you have twenty groups, and you want the probability that every one of them has at least two users. That is $0.003842^{20} \approx 4.92\times 10^{-49}$.

Comment: uhm no, he wants to calculate for each group seperately, so in that group the probability is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done easily in linear time , suppose that $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_{20}$ are the probabilities that each person participates.

The probability that at least two persons participate is the same as $1$ minus the probability that no one shows up or exactly one person shows up:

$1-\prod\limits_{i=1}^{20}(1-p_i)-\sum\limits_{i=1} \frac{p_i}{(1-p_i)}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{20}(1-p_i)$

we can rewrite this as:

$1-(1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{20}\frac{p_i}{(1-p_i)})\prod\limits_{i=1}^{20}(1-p_i)$

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understand that you intended to calculate the probabilities per each group right? May I kindly ask you to simply your solution by showing its application for a single group (in which there are 5 users)?

Comment: This formula breaks when there is at least one $p_a$ that is equal to $1$. But that case is easy because the probability that exactly one person shows up is just $\prod (1-p_i)$ over all $i\neq a$

Answer (score 1):

One way:

$$P(at\ least\ 2) = 1 - P(none) - P(exactly\ one)$$

with

$$P(exactly\ one) = P(1st) \cdot P(none\ of\ 2nd, 3rd, \ldots, 20th) + P(2nd) \cdot P(none\ of\ 1st, 3rd, 4th, \ldots, 20th) + \cdots$$

But **this only works if your participation is independent.**